# How do I use new <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Module"> in my Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, office-addins, office365-apps

At the Build 2016 Microsoft announced [that now developers can extend Outlook 2016 using new extension point called "Module"](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P572).

I have installed Visual Studio Update 2 and the latest tools for Office. I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

Now I am trying to add new "Module" to my manifest file, but there is no such type available: [see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIIIK.png).

I have also tried Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-ModuleExtension sample project and was able to run it and deploy manifest to my Office 365 account, but I can not see the new Module in my Outlook.

Am I missing something? How can I use new Module extension point for Outlook?

Comment: Did you upgrade your Office Desktop 2016 ? Only latest builds support VersionOverridesV1_1 https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-ModuleExtension/issues/2

Comment: Yes, I have Office Desktop 2016. Chuck-at-MSFT says I need to find build 65XX. I saw you have successfully implemented module extension which means you got the build somewhere. Where did you find it?

Comment: Hi Peter, if you're on click to run, then you should have a higher build number than what you're reporting. Can you click on "FILE", then on "Office Account" on the left. You should see "Update Options" button there. Can you click on that and make sure updates are enabled?

Comment: I have auto-update enabled + I clicked "Updated Now" and it looked like it did something by I still have version 16.0.60.... And not it says I am up to date: [https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9dHk/KS2BMUoLr](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9dHk/KS2BMUoLr)

Comment: It looks like that with "module" extension point, you have to restart outlook desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use build 65XX or higher for extensions to work.

Comment: Where can I find this build? I have Office 16.0.6001.1068 (Click to Run version) which I downloaded from office365 portal. I also had version from MSDN before click to run version which did not work either.

Comment: Chuck-at-MSFT is correct about the build, but today this build is not generally available. In order to install it you should use **Office Click to Run Deployment Tool** and whether: become an [Office Insider](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider) if you use Office 365 Home editing or [Install First Release build](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=722564) if you use Office 365 for Business. Platforms other than Windows Desktop are not yet supported.